yt-dlp doesn't see ffmpeg, although it is specified in the buildozer requirements
I am writing an application using yt-dlp to download videos, and when I try to merge the two formats via yt-dlp, I get the following error:
[WARNING] You have requested merging of multiple formats but ffmpeg is not installed. The formats won't be merged (received from logcat)
My buildozer requirements:
requirements = ffmpeg,python3,kivy,yt_dlp,python-for-android,pillow,kivymd
how can I fix it?
I've tried adding ffprobe to the requirements, and it doesn't work. I also tried changing the yt-dlp parameters, but obviously, it didn't help.

ffmpeg and ffprobe are not Python modules but C/C++ programs which you may have to install manually from page FFmpeg

@furas Thanks for answer! But as I know ffmpeg installing from python4android recipes (its not Python lib). So how i can install ffmpeg and ffprobe in buildozer not as python lib?
